# How to identify frequencies of multiple columns based on condition using R

Tags: r, sapply

I have a dataframe which contains 63 columns and 50 rows. I have given below a toy dataset.

```
>df
 rs_1 rs_2 rs_3 rs_4 ... rs_60 A.Ag    B.Ag   C.Ag         
 0    0    1    2    ... 1     02:/01  02:/07  03:07/04:01
 1    2    1    2    ... 0     02:/01  02:/07  03:07/04:01
 2    1    1    2    ... 2     02:/01  02:/07  03:07/04:01
 0    0    1    0    ... 2     02:/01  02:/07  03:07/04:01
```

Now I need to find the highest frequencies of the columns (A.Ag, B.Ag and C.Ag) for each rs_* =0, 1 and 2 separately. The desire outcome would be for example rs_*=0

```
rs_id   Code    A.Ag    Code      B.Ag  Code     C.Ag
rs_1    02:/01  2       02:/07     5     03:07   5
rs_2    02:/01  3       01:/05     2     05:00   4
```

could you please help me with this? I tried with the following function

```
for (i in 1:60){
  if (file[,i]==0)
 {
 temp1 = data.frame(sort(table(file[,61]), decreasing = TRUE)) #onlr for A.Ag coulmn
 temp1$Var1 = names(file)[i]
 res_types = rbind(res_types, temp1)
 }
 }
```

I got the number of frequencies and rs_id. But could not get the code. Can anyone help me with this?

The desire outcome will be

```
rs_id   Code    Combination A.A Combination  B.Ag Combination   C.Ag
rs_1    0       1:01/1:01   7   13:02/13:02  2   03:04/03:04    3   
rs_1    0       1:01/11:01  5   13:02/49:01  2   03:04/15:02    3
rs_1    0       1:01/2:01   4   13:02/57:01  2   03:04/7:01     3   
rs_1    1       1:01/2:05   3   13:02/8:01   4   06:02/06:02    3
rs_1    1       1:01/24:02  3   14:01/14:02  3   06:02/15:02    3
rs_1    1       1:01/24:02  3   14:01/14:02  2   06:02/15:02    3   
rs_2    0       1:01/31:01  3   15:01/15:01  1   06:02/3:03     4       
rs_2    0       11:01/2:01  4   15:01/18:01  1   06:02/3:04     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to do this using `data.table` package. Explanation inline.

```
library(data.table)
#convert into a long format
longDat <- melt(dat, measure.vars=patterns("^rs"), variable.name="rs_id", 
    value.name="val_id")

#for each group of rs_id (rs_1, ..., rs_60) and val_id in (0,1,2), 
#count the frequency of each code
longDat[,
        unlist(
            lapply(c("A.Ag","B.Ag","C.Ag"), 
                function(x) setNames(aggregate(get(x), list(get(x)), length), c("Code", x))
            ), 
        recursive=FALSE), 
    by=c("rs_id", "val_id")]
```

Is this what you are looking for? Does this help?

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("rs_1,rs_2,rs_3,rs_4,rs_60,A.Ag,B.Ag,C.Ag
0,0,1,2,1,02:/01,02:/07,03:07/04:01
1,2,1,2,0,02:/01,02:/07,03:07/04:01
2,1,1,2,2,02:/01,02:/07,03:07/04:01
0,0,1,0,2,02:/01,02:/07,03:07/04:01")
```

---

edit: OP request to retrieve top 3 for each rs_id, val_id and *.Ag

It is prob more readable to do it one *.Ag at a time, count and then take top 3 and then finally merge all the results as follows:

```
library(data.table)
#convert into a long format
longDat <- melt(dat, measure.vars=patterns("^rs"), variable.name="rs_id", 
    value.name="val_id")

ids <- c("rs_id", "val_id")
Reduce(function(dt1,dt2) merge(dt1,dt2,by=ids,all=TRUE),
    lapply(c("A.Ag","B.Ag","C.Ag"), function(x) {
        res <- longDat[, list(.N), by=c(ids, x)][order(-N)]
        setnames(res[, head(.SD ,3L), by=ids], c(x, "N"), c(paste0(x,"_Code"), x))
    }))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. But in the output, I need only first three highest frequencies. How can I filter that?

Comment: thanks, @MSM. can you clarify what do you mean by the first three highest? how do you order before you take the first 3 rows?

Comment: @MSM can you share your whole dataset? I am unable to reproduce the output without your dataset

Comment: Based on A.Ag, B.Ag and C.Ag columns. For example, for 1st rs_id and the code 0, I need the highest number of A.Ag, B. Ag and C.Ag.   Ive include the sample output in my post

Comment: Ive added the desire output in my post